# If I mix 10 mg of salt in 1 liter of water... Will I drink exactly 0.01mg of salt per ml?

Tags: mixtures

If I dissolve 10 mg of salt in 1 liter of water, will every milliliter of that water contain exactly 0.01 mg of salt? In other words, is a solution uniform in composition, or will there be areas within the solution where the salt has a higher concentration than other areas?

Comment: Erm … yeah? So … what is the question?

Comment: Not exactly because the salt as a volume

Comment: @Jan The question is : are every 1ml of water containing exactly 0.01mg of salt ?

Comment: @Clippy it depends if your salt is or not soluble in water, what do you know about it. ? It depends on the temperature too. And Your salt has at least a volume. So if 10mg of your salt is equivalent to 1mL the concentration will not be 10mg/L ..

Comment: Clippy, see Benzene's edit -- if it doesn't match what you're actually trying to ask, please roll it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I mix 10 mg of salt in 1 liter of water

If mixing means dissolving the salt in water...

> Will I drink exactly 0.01mg of salt per ml?

Yes. Not exactly $0.010000~\mathrm{mg}$, but $0.01~\mathrm{mg}$

> So if I drink 100 ml I will also drink 1mg of salt ?

Yes.

Note that the answer assumes that the water used did not contain the same salt before adding the 10 milligrams.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of factors at work here. Assuming that the addition of the salt does not change the total volume of the solution and that it dissolves completely, you are correct. The definition of a [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution) is a "homogeneous mixture composed of two or more substances." Since a solution is homogeneous, this means that the salt is evenly distributed within the water, and thus you will consume exactly .01 mg of salt per mL, implying in turn that you will also drink 1 mg of salt per 100 mL. If, however, the volume of your solution changes by adding the salt, you will consume slightly less than your calculated ratio of 1 mg per 100 mL, as there is more volume over which the salt is uniformly distributed. In addition, if your salt solution becomes saturated, leaving some undissolved salt at the bottom, your concentration will once again become lower than 1 mg per 100 mL. Exactly how much the concentration would change depends on the amount that the salt changes the volume as well as the amount of salt that fails to dissolve.